# I don't get 'et al.' when I have a long author list

Tags: bibtex, natbib, author-number

I am using an article with a long author list, like this:

```
author = {{H.Oumerachi and A.Kortenhaus and William Allsop and Maarten and 
  Groot and Roger Crouch and Han Vrijling and Hessel Voortman }}
```

`natbib` is supposed to use a long author list only the first time, and then use `et al.` However, I get a long author list every time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: If you have two sets of braces, as shown, then you are saying that the list should not be processed at all (it's treated as a single name).

Comment: Besides the comment about the double brace, I'd also turn this into `{Oumerachi, H. and ...}` so BibTeX knows about the first and surnames.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the double braces and replace with a single brace; separate first names from family names:

```
author = {{H.Oumerachi and A.Kortenhaus and William Allsop and Maarten and  
  Groot and Roger Crouch and Han Vrijling and Hessel Voortman }},

author = {H. Oumerachi and A. Kortenhaus and William Allsop and Maarten  
 Groot and Roger Crouch and Han Vrijling and Hessel Voortman},
```

(An "and" seemed unnecessary.)

Comment: I took the liberty of pointing out another weak point in the OP's input.